# What is the language used in Mozilla's manual site?

Tags: programming-languages, mozilla, manual

I accidentally visited [Mozilla manual site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TCPSocket), and I discovered the language is not familiar. AFAIK, this isn't Javascript. It looks like Java, C#, Go or a sort of them, but I can't figure out what the language actually is.

From *API overview* section in the page:

```
interface TCPSocket{
  readonly attribute DOMString host;
  readonly attribute unsigned short port;
  readonly attribute boolean ssl;
  readonly attribute unsigned long bufferedAmount;
  readonly attribute DOMString binaryType;
  readonly attribute DOMString readyState;

  TCPSocket open(DOMString host, unsigned short port, [object options]);
  TCPServerSocket listen(unsigned short port, [object options, [unsigned short backlog]])
  void upgradeToSecure();
  void suspend();
  void resume();
  void close();
  boolean send(in jsval data);

  attribute onopen;
  attribute ondrain;
  attribute ondata;
  attribute onerror;
  attribute onclose;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Interface Definition Language by Object Management Group. Introduction to the language may be found at http://www.omg.org/gettingstarted/omg_idl.htm , [full specs of the upcoming version](http://www.omg.org/spec/IDL35/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Well, I'm agree with your comment but I'm not sure what part of specification would be sufficent. Anyway, I'll change the URL to the main site of the Object Management Group... Thank you for the suggestion.